# How can I check the substring of a field inside an SQL Insert statement?

Tags: sql

I need help trying to do an Insert statement based on a serial number match. The field in the table "`EDI40025.Bundle_Serial_Num`" is 20 chars long, and the "`SerialNumber.Text`" that is 6 chars. Can I somehow take the substring of the Bundle_Serial_Num so that I only check 6 chars so that it will match the text field?

For example my `Bundle_Serial_Num` is `"UNS40000000000447022"` and the SerialNumber.Text is `"447022"`. I want to compare the last 6 of the `Bundle_Serial_Num` with the 6 from the text field.

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO EDI40021 (Vendor_Order, BOL_Num, Cust_Part_Num)  
             WHERE (EDI40025.Bundle_Serial_Num = '" + SerialNumber.Text + "')";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `RIGHT` function to grab the last six characters of the serial number.

```
WHERE (RIGHT(EDI40025.Bundle_Serial_Num, 6) = '" + SerialNumber.Text + "')";
```

However, you most likely want to re-write your query as a parametrized query if possible as you are currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Also, your query doesn't quite look right, because you're not `SELECTING` from table EDI40025.

Comment: There is more to the SELECT statement as well I just didn't include it cause its not relevent. I do an INNER JOIN on table EDI40025.